# fetching values from class

Tags: java

I am new to java. My problem is

I have created a class for all the database connections.Now i want to access that class methods in another class.So i have created an object of that class.
But when i am using that object to access the methods of database class it is showing the error that

```
"dbcon(object) cannot be resolved to a type"
```

I can't understand what is the issue.

Please help.

Comment: Without seeing some example code, no-one can help you.

Comment: compiler should be telling you something and looks like visibility issue.

Answer (score 2):

**Make a valid reference.**

The error you are getting is because your code which uses the class is not able to reference the class.  If these classes are in different packages, you will need to add an `import` line to the top of the class you're working in to import the `dbcon` class.

You should also be aware that case matters.  `dbcon` is not the same as `DBCon`.  In Java, it is a standard that all class names should begin with uppercase letters and all variables with lowercase letters.  So, the class `dbcon` is at the very least named improperly.  This standard helps to identify and resolve problems like the one you're having before they ever happen.

Finally, I would highly suggest that you work with some sort of IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliossr1).  This software can make your development process much easier by helping you solve common problems like these through suggested steps.

Answer (score 0):

Heres a working reference example. Look at your code if it is close or similiar (apart from class and methodnames):

```
package com.example.util;

// imports if required

public class MyConnection {

   // attribute storing the real connection
   Connection conn = null;

   // constructor to create a connection
   public MyConnection() {
     this.conn = magicMethodToCreateConnection(); // to be implemented
   }

   // getter method for that connection
   public Connection getConnection() {
     return conn;
   }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.application;

import com.example.util.*;
// more imports if required

public class ConenctionUser {

   public static useConnection() {
     MyConnection myConn = new MyConnection();
     Connection conn = myConn.getConnecion();
     // now we can use conn
   }
}
```